# How to sum 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to sum two numbers but it gives me NaN. How can i make it work? I tried already with parseInt but same thing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="num1">5</p>
  <p id="num2">5</p>
  <p id="res">1</p>
</body>
<script>
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  var res = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: 1: p's do not have value, they have innerText or textContent, 2 - you need parseInt or + as in `var res = +num1 + +num2;`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Also have the script tag before the </body>

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="num1">5</p>
        <p id="num2">5</p>
        <p id="res">1</p>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML;
                var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML;
                var res = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);

                document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Already answered in the comment under the question. Please also give some explanation when you answer

Comment: First, is that, the script tag should be inside the body or head element. Then to insure the javascript code run after the document has loaded, use window.onload event. Last is that, you are accessing the p content, so, use innerHTML.

Comment: or innerText or textContent - so the only issue you have added is the script tag.

Comment: When a question is answered and voted up, it canot be deleted

Comment: Also please use addEventListener instead of onload

Comment: Lastly use the `[<>]` snippet editor to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you should use Number(document.getElementById("num1").innerText),because the value property of p tag is not existing.

Answer (score -1):

You have used "value", instead of innerHTML for getting the number.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="num1">5</p>
  <p id="num2">5</p>
  <p id="res">1</p>
</body>
<script>
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML);
  var res = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Already answered by the comment under the question. It should be closed as "typo-type" - also you missed the <script> tags are outside the body

Comment: Yep, it was answered at the same time while I was sending mine. And its true that I missed the body issue, which even that it works, it won't validate. Although I think that downvote it for that reason is a bit hard.